# How to find entities where key does not exist

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `productattributes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attribute_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Sample data:

```
id      product_id  attribute_id  value
651048  81546       132           0
651049  81546       133           1440
651050  81546       134           1440
707380  81546       136           1088

674291  84645       132           0
674292  84645       134           70560
674293  84645       133           144
674294  84645       136           2058
674295  84645       137           SS34
674296  84645       142           213
674297  84645       147           AB
674298  84645       154           F
```

And I wish to know when a product_id does NOT have the attribute_id "136" set.
From the sample data above, both of the products have a attribute_id "136" set to some value.

If one products does not have this attribute, the attribute_id isnt even there (is NOT set to NULL).
Like this:

```
1   5000    132 0
2   5000    133 1440
3   5000    134 1440
```

How can I query this table to know what products does NOT have `attribute_id` 136 set to any value?

What have I done so far?

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM sbb.productattributes
WHERE EXISTS(attribute_id = 136) ORDER BY product_id LIMIT 100000
```

Something like that. But I understand that you have to use a second SELECT query inside the EXIST() statement. But for me everything is inside that one table.

A perfect result would be to see (from the sample data above), that product_id 5000 DOES NOT have a value for attribute_id 136. I dont want to see the other products, as they do have a value for attribute_id 136.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to exclude all products that have attribute_id = 136:

```
select *
from productattributes p1
where not exists (select 1 from productattributes p2
                  where p1.product_id = p2.product_id
                    and p2.attribute_id = 136)
```